# Laravel: CSRF Token invalid after user logs out?

Tags: php, laravel-5

A logged in user can edit his profile. If he presses "Save" then the data will be send by AJAX and he gets an success message:
[image]

If the user logs out in a different tab, then the "Save" button does not work anymore. I would like to let the user know with an ajax warning(just as above, but in red instead of green), that he is logged out.

This is my code:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth',['except' => 'updateContact']);
}

public function updateContact(Request $request)
{
  if(!Auth::check()){
   return json_encode(['status' => false, 'msg' => 'You are not logged in! Chanes are not saved!']);
}
```

However, this does not work. THe method is not returning anything. Instead I get a warning

> The page has expired due to inactivity.

It looks to me that the CSRF token is invalid as soon as I logout a user. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because CSRF Token is the Laravel's session token, when the user logs out, CSRF changes

Comment: @nitrex can I catch the CSRF exception when the user is not logged in? Because I would like to use CSRF when hes logged in, and if not he should just return an error message, no need for CSRF token because no changes will be applied.

Comment: You can use $request->cookie('XSRF-TOKEN') to check if the session token is set, just check if(empty($request->cookie('XSRF-TOKEN'))

Comment: @nitrex but as far as I understand, he will never even execute `updateContact` if the token is not matching?

Comment: You can check like this
 if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {            
        return redirect('/')->withErrors(['token_error' => 'Sorry, your session seems to have expired. Please try again.']);
    }

Answer (score 1):

You check your CSRF Exception like this

```
 if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {            
        return redirect('/')->withErrors(['token_error' => 'Sorry, your session seems to have expired. Please try again.']);
    }
```

Comment: Where should I put this conde, inside my Controller in `function updateContact`?

Comment: Yes, Put need to put it inside controller function